# SQL Server 2014 Password Won't Change

Tags: sql-server

I recently set up SQL Server 2014 Express on my computer. During the installation process I merely selected Windows authentication, assuming I would be able to create other accounts later. I tested several things with C# using integrated authentication.

The problem arose when I attempted to use an account. I logged in using Windows authentication to change the `sa` password in SQL Server Management Studio. But when I attempt to so, and close the dialog, open it again, then the password is back to the 15 character default which I do not know. Enforce Policy is not on and I have no idea what might be causing this...

Comment: [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about enabling mixed mode and sa.

Comment: @pianisht1119 How do you know the password is set to 15 characters ? The reason I'm asking is if you're simply counting the asterixes that appear by default, that's never going to match up with the actual password.

Comment: @AshwinNair actually yes, I was just counting the black dots in the password box. Does that mean that this could be a completely unrelated problem as to why my password isn't working?

Comment: the count of dots/astericks doesn't tells you that your password is of this length

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check if you've enabled mixed mode authentication by:

1. right click on Server name after you've logged in as a windows user
2. Click Properties
3. Click Security
4. Check that the 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode' option is selected.

[image: Enable Mixed Mode authentication]

Then you can change the password for sa by going expanding the Server item and going to Security -> Logins -> Right click on sa -> Click Properties
Change the password here and CLICK OK.

Log out, log back in as sa, after selecting SQL Server Authentication just above where you enter the user name.

[image: Login using sql server authentication]

Comment: Authentication mode was my problem. Great and comprehensive answer, thanks!

Comment: you save my life!